# when I reload page give me oldValue inside of new Value chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I try newValue assign to variable and use it but when I reload page that data be oldValue how to solve this problem?

my_script.js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    $(".info-more").append($("<a class='my-button'></a>"));

    var token;
    chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
        token = changes.token_data.newValue;
    }); 

    $('.dropali-button').on('click',function(){
        console.log(token);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your value to [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

Saving:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({token: '...'})
```

Reading:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('token', function(storageItem) {
    console.log(storageItem.token); // your saved token
});
```

Comment: Yeah i know this way but i want check tracking without reload page by the way i set data in background.js like token_data . I want always listen to changing @Deliaz